# What is --sys-prefix that appears in various jupyter commands?

Tags: python, jupyter

In layman's term, what is `--sys-prefix` that appears with many jupyter comamnds, for example [here](https://jupyter-notebook.readthedocs.io/en/4.x/examples/Notebook/rstversions/Distributing%20Jupyter%20Extensions%20as%20Python%20Packages.html).

I always had problems to understand what it actually does.
How does this work in context of using asdf-vm python or having activated conda/virtualenv environments.

Comment: From the shell, do `jupyter serverextension --help` to see help that includes this argument.